# Can you change how window.localStorage.setItem() works on a certain webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, local-storage

I want to redefine window.localStorage.setItem() so that it gets intercepted every time it's called anywhere on a webpage, and another version of this function is executed. I need to do this because I want to use a custom localStorage and so I need to add a third parameter which specifies where to save those data.
I was reading about Javascript Proxies but I'm not sure whether they do what I want to accomplish. Does it make sense anyway? Can I even do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

Although I would say it's not advised.  Creating a wrapper function to do this would be better.

```
function mySetItem(key, value) {
  console.log(key, value);
  return localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}
```

But if you really want to intercept, you could do something like ->

```
const old = localStorage.setItem; //store old method

localStorage.setItem = 
  function (...args) { 
     console.log(args); //intercept, args
     return old.apply(localStorage, arguments); //call native
  }
```